# Reducing repetition in C

Tags: c

I haven't included any code because it's not important to my question, but say I have a statement like `if (g_sound == 1){printf("\a");}` (of course I am just using a shorter example), how could I use this code all over my program while not having so much repetitiveness? Is there some type of variable which you could link to and have the code in that variable executed? So that half my code isn't the same thing over and over again... All help is much appreciated!
**UPDATE:** Thank you all for your helpful comments, I figured out that using a function would be the most optimal since it is a 20 line code I need to have executed! Thanks once again!

Comment: That's what functions are for.

Comment: And preprocessor macros.

Comment: Though rarely the driving consideration, just be aware you will add a bit of overhead with function calls. The macro call is simply replaced with the macro verbatim by the preprocessor. The goal should always be readability and maintainability. tzaman and Lee cover your options, you simply balance your needs to find the result that is suited best for your implementation. Note, if you are new to writing macros, be aware there are subtle nuances that can cause you no end of pain if you go that route.

Comment: I would find a good C tutorial, if you aren't using one already. It will explain this, and a lot of other things you'll need to know.

Answer (score 1):

If the statement is really that simple (or at least optimal) then use a macro:

```
#define THIS_IS_NOT_A_FUNCTION(X) if (x == 1){ printf ("\a");}
```

Then the macro is used like this:

```
// do some tedious task that I can't be bother typing out fully:
THIS_IS_NOT_A_FUNCTION(g_sound);
```

As David C. Rankin pointed out in his comment, macros are expanded to their defined value pre-compile time so don't have the overhead of calling a function. The downside is that the code can become unreadable if macros are used too liberally.

If the statement is a complex operation it may pay to write a function and call that.